# Position and different meanings of "still" in the sentence

Tags: word-meaning

Is there any difference in meanings of "still" if I put it in different places in the sentence?:
 He had a fever...
 1. He lay still in the bed
 2. He still lay in the bed
 3. Still he lay in the bed

Answer (score 1):

To lie still [not lay] means to not move. **Still is an adjective**.

He still lay [past tense of to lie [on a bed] =He continued to lie on the bed. **Still is an adverb**.

Still, he lay in bed. **That use of still is nevertheless**. **A conjunctive adverb**. Please note: still used like that implies something occurred in a previous sentence.

**The telephone was ringing loudly. Still, he lay in bed**.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a great deal.

1. To "lay still" is to not move.
2. "Still" right after a subject indicates that you expected them to be doing something different.
3. "Still" at the beginning of a sentence indicates that you expected the whole scene to change.